# Why does PIL thumbnail not resizing correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create and save a thumbnail image when saving the original user image in the `userProfile` model in my project, below is my code:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    THUMB_SIZE = 45, 45
    image = Image.open(join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.headshot.name))

    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(self.headshot.name)
    image.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)        
    thumb_fn = fn + '-thumb' + ext
    tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
    image.save(tf.name, 'JPEG')
    self.headshot_thumb.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf.name)), save=False)
    tf.close()

    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Every thing is working OK, just this one thing.

The problem is that the thumbnail function only sets the width to `45` and doesn't change the ratio aspect of the image so I am getting an image of `45*35` for the one that I am testing on (short image).

Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong? How to force the aspect ratio I want?

P.S.: I've tried all the methods for size: `tupal: THUMB_SIZE = (45, 45)` and entering the sizes directly to the thumbnail function also.

Another question: what is the deference between resize and thumbnail functions in PIL? When to use resize and when to use thumbnail?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [*image.thumbnail()*](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.thumbnail) function will maintain the aspect ratio of the original image.

Use [*image.resize()*](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.resize) instead.

**UPDATE**

```
image = image.resize(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)        
thumb_fn = fn + '-thumb' + ext
tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
image.save(tf.name, 'JPEG')
```

Comment: 10x, but I've tried also image.resize(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS) where the THUMB_RESIZE is a tupal (THUMB_RESIZE = (45,45) and it is not resizing at all now... Any thing else over here? (that is what i read in the link)... Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank again ShadowCloud, i found the problem... You answer was great, but resize function return a value that need to save, and thumbnail function is void so no need to save, so if using image.resize(...) it need to be image = image.resize(...), took me some time but i got it...can you please fix it in your answer? :-)

Comment: there is also `image.fit(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)` which will use the given dimensions but maintain aspect ratio by cropping the image. see: http://djangosaur.tumblr.com/post/422589280/django-resize-thumbnail-image-pil

Answer (score 6):

Given:

```
import Image # Python Imaging Library
THUMB_SIZE= 45, 45
image # your input image
```

If you want to resize any image to size 45×45, you should use:

```
new_image= image.resize(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

However, if you want a resulting image of size 45×45 while the input image is resized keeping its aspect ratio and filling the missing pixels with black:

```
new_image= Image.new(image.mode, THUMB_SIZE)
image.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS) # in-place
x_offset= (new_image.size[0] - image.size[0]) // 2
y_offset= (new_image.size[1] - image.size[1]) // 2
new_image.paste(image, (x_offset, y_offset))
```