# Pillow's Image.thumbnail() doesn't do anything

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I try to make thumbnails using the following code:

```
import Image

# Skipping creation of file-like object 'f'
im = Image.open(f)
im.thumbnail((256, im.height))
im.save(f, 'WebP')
f.flush()
```

The [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=thumbnail#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) say "This method modifies the image to contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger than the given size." Thus, I expect the output to be fit within 256px width while [preserving the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177532/why-does-pil-thumbnail-not-resizing-correctly). The above code, however, has no effect and output image has the same resolution as input, which is always larger than 256px width.

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillow docs specify that file needs to be opened in binary mode, but with `w+b` used here new image actually gets appended to the old one. It needs to be fully loaded to memory and file to be truncated. The working code is:

```
import Image

# Skipping creation of file-like object 'f'
im = Image.open(f)
im.load()
f.seek(0)
f.file.truncate()
im.thumbnail((256, im.height))
im.save(f, 'WebP')
f.flush()
```